# Linear Algebra Problem: Eigenvalue and Eigenvector problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

﻿
Below is the problem

There is a invertible matrix B:

$B=\begin{matrix}3&2&1\\1&2&2\\1&2&1\end{matrix}$

﻿A is 3x3 matrix ,and eigenvalue of AB is 1,2,3 .

Also,eigenvector of AB is (1,1,0), (1,-1,0),(1,1,1) .

Find eigenvalue and eigenvector of BA

This problem took a lot of calculation...
I wonder if there is a faster way to solve the problem

Comment: Uhm I got like 5 exercises and I need some help

Comment: Please update your questions first by telling us what you did and what your issues are. Also making some computations will help to understand the problem... even if it’s not fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is to notice that
$$
BA = B(AB)B^{-1}.
$$
With this, we have enough information to conclude that the eigenvalues of $BA$ are the same as the eigenvalues of $AB$, and if $x$ is an eigenvector of $AB$ associated with $\lambda$, then $Bx$ will be an eigenvector of $BA$ associated with the same eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! By the way how can I conclude " that the eigenvalues of BA are the same as the eigenvalues of AB " by BA=B(AB)B-1 ? Since I'm a novice I would be grateful if you supplement your answer thank you

Comment: Are you aware of what it means for two matrices to be "similar"?

Comment: Yes I am your formula shows that BA and AB are similar right?

Comment: Aha now I understood what you mean since BA and AB are similar matrix, BA has eigenvalues of AB, and eigenvectors of BA are Bx since B is in the position of A=M-1BM-